# Where is my Segmentation Fault occuring? C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

below I have some code that creates a singly linked list and stores some points in it. It compiles, but for the life of me, I can't not figure out where and why I am getting a segmentation fault. It happens right when the program starts.

Also, before you tell me, I know this sorted linked list algorithm is very inefficient, but I have been trying to get this to work for awhile now and I am just trying to get something working at this point.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

File 1:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"

typedef struct node
{
    Point p;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insertAtFront(node **start, Point *ip);
void sort(node *start);
void swap(node *a, node *b);
void printList(node *start);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Point *insertPoint;
    node *head = NULL;

    point_set(insertPoint,7.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);
    sort(head);

    point_set(insertPoint,1.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);
    sort(head);

    point_set(insertPoint,4.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);
    sort(head);

    point_set(insertPoint,3.0,1.0);
    insertAtFront(&head,insertPoint);
    sort(head);

    printList(head);
}

void insertAtFront(node **start, Point *ip)
{
    node *node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node1->p = *ip;
    node1->next = *start;
    *start = node1;
}

void sort(node *start)
{
    Point *tp1 = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    Point *tp2 = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    int swapped;
    node *node1;
    node *node2 = NULL;
    double d1;
    double d2;
    if(node1 == NULL)
        return;
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        node1 = start;
        *tp1 = node1->p;
        *tp2 = node1->next->p;
        d1 = distanceFromOrigin(tp1);
        d2 = distanceFromOrigin(tp2);
        while(node1->next != node2)
        {
            if(d1 > d2)
            {
                swap(node1,node1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            node1 = node1->next;
        }
        node2 = node1;
    }
    while(swapped);
}

void swap(node *a, node *b)
{
    Point *tp;
    *tp = a->p;
    a->p = b->p;
    b->p = *tp;
}

void printList(node *start)
{
    node *temp = start;
    Point *tp = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    printf("\n");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        *tp = temp->p;
        printf("Point: (%g,%g) - Distance: %g", point_getX(tp), point_getY(tp), distanceFromOrigin(tp));
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"
#include <math.h>

void point_translate(Point *p, double x, double y)
{
    point_set(p,(point_getX(p)+x),(point_getY(p)+y));
}

double point_distance(const Point *p1, const Point *p2)
{
    double temp1 = (point_getX(p1) - point_getX(p2));
    double temp2 = (point_getY(p1) - point_getY(p2));
    double temp3 = (temp1*temp1)+(temp2*temp2);
    double dist = sqrt(temp3);
    return dist;
}

double distanceFromOrigin(const Point *p1)
{
    double x = point_getX(p1);
    double y = point_getY(p1);
    double temp = (x*x)+(y*y);
    double dist = sqrt(temp);
    return dist;
}
```

File 3:

```
#ifndef _POINT_H_
#define _POINT_H_

typedef struct Point 
{
  double x;
  double y;
} Point;

void point_translate(Point *p, double x, double y);
double point_distance(const Point *p1, const Point *p2);
double distanceFromOrigin(const Point *p1);

static inline double point_getX(const Point *p)
{
  return p->x;
}
static inline double point_getY(const Point *p)
{
  return p->y;
}
static inline Point *point_set(Point *p, double x, double y)
{
  p->x = x; 
  p->y = y;
  return p;
}



#endif
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: If you show us the error message, that might be a hint.

Comment: Show us Valgrind's report please

Comment: Lean how to use a debugger in order to be able to find problems like this by yourself.

Comment: It still reads "Segmentation Fault" after allocating space for insertPoint. I added some printf() statements around for some dirty debugging where I create the first insertPoint but it doesn't even reach it before faulting out.

Comment: Of cours it read still  "Segmentation Fault"  but it shows you where the segmentation faut occurs. You can inspect the content of variables, you can inspect the call stack etc. Googling gdb tutorial" or similar should point you to tons of information.

Comment: compile your program with `gcc -g` in order to get useful information with gdb.

Comment: gdb shows the Segmentation Fault occurring in sort function. Line : "*tps = node1->next->p". Any help there?

Comment: How do you expect the sorter handles the end of the list?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, right at the start is correct:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   Point *insertPoint;   // this pointer points nowhere
   node *head = NULL;

   point_set(insertPoint,7.0,1.0);   // still point_set dereferences it
```

Comment: After adding "insertPoint = malloc(sizeof(Point));", it still reads "Segmentation Fault" after trying to run

Comment: The you can suspect `insertAtFront` or `sort`.  In `sort` you have a test `if (node1 == NULL)` when `node1` has no value,

Comment: Fixed, but still does it. I put in a "printf("--");" at the very beginning of the program before I even create the first insertPoint, and it gives me "Segmentation Fault" before it even reaches the printf statement

Comment: @drewfiss90: Always log debug stuff to an unbuffered output stream (like `fprintf(stderr, "--")` or flush the output stream after printing to it (like `printf("--"); flush(stdout)`.